# Django - How to map object from another API and send in GET response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to map object from another API and send in GET response. I'm going to change only `id` of received object. Let's assume I get data from another API in such format:

```
{
  "id": "31242",
  "name": "sth1",
  "price": "44",
  "data": "2017-06-07",
}
```

In my database I have table `object1` with values:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "sth1",
},
{
  "id": "124",
  "name": "sth2",
},
{
  "id": "125",
  "name": "sth3",
}
```

Field `name` is unique both in data from API and in data from database. I receive an object named `sth1`. So now I would like to find it in my database and get his `id`, replace with `id` from API and send GET response. In this case my response would look in this way:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "sth1",
  "price": "44",
  "data": "2017-06-07",
}
```

At this moment this is my URL - `url(r'^data/(?P<name>\w+)$', views.DataList),` 
but I would like to have such URL - `localhost:8000/data?name=sth`
My`view.py`:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def DataList(request, name=None):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        quote = getDataFromAPI().get(name)
        return Response(quote)
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class Object1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Object1
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
```

`models.py`:

```
class Object1(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I have done it in this way:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def DataList(request):

    t = request.GET.get("t","")
    quote = getDataFromAPI().get(t)
    id = Object1.objects.get(t=t)
    quote["id"] = id
    return Response(quote)
```

But I get error:
`TypeError: Object of type 'Object1' is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, your view should look somewhat like this,

```
@api_view(['GET']) 
def DataList(request): 
    t = request.GET.get("t","") 
    quote = getDataFromAPI().get(t) 
    id = Object1.objects.get(t=t).id #put the id of the object in the variable.
                   #not the object itself.
    quote["id"] = id 
    return Response(quote)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the url from
`url(r'^data/(?P<name>\w+)$', views.DataList)` to `localhost:8000/data?name=sth` you'd need to change your api endpoint from

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def DataList(request, name=None):
```

to

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def DataList(request):
    name = request.GET.get("name","")
```

and then take the id of object from your database by querying

```
id = Object1.objects.get(name=name)
```

and then updating id in response to be sent

```
quote["id"] = id
```

Comment: If I had to do this like in the first post it still doesn't work. I have updated my post and described error.